# Como remover caracter do vetor ao pressionar backspace em c

Tags: c

Boa Noite.... Estou fazendo um sistema de login automatico e a validação funcionou agr o unico problema é que não da pra se apagar o caracter anterior caso o usuario erre a letra, gostaria de saber como se pegaria o evento do usuario apertar a tecla backspace para apagar o caracter errado obs - codigo abaixo

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <windows.h>
   #include <string.h>
   char vetor[50];
   char user[]= "usuario";
   char senha[]= "senha";
   int i = 0, c, t=0, j=0, cont=0;

   int main(){

       void Validacao(char vetor[50],int valida, char desejado[50]);
       void ValidacaoSenha(char vetor[50],int valida, char desejado[50]);

       //para entrada e reconhecimento da senha versão 1.0
       printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\tLogin >> ");
       Validacao(vetor,strlen(user),user);
   }

   void Validacao(char vetor[50],int valida, char desejado[50]){

       int i = 0, c, t=0, j=0, cont=0;

       do{
           c=getch();
           fflush(stdin);
           vetor[i] = c;

           printf("%c", vetor[i]);
           i++;

               if(vetor[j] == desejado[j]){
                   cont++;
               }
               j++;

           if(cont==valida){
               t=1;
           }
       } while (t!=1);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Em primeiro lugar, `getch()` e `fflush(stdin)` são duas das coisas mais nefastas em C; a primeira não faz parte do padrão e a segunda gera comportamento indefinido. Se a intenção é apenas ler uma string do usuário, e depois comparar com outra string, não há necessidade de fazer caractere a caractere, faça tudo com strings mesmo:

```
do {
    scanf(" %s", vetor);
} while(strcmp(vetor, desejado) != 0);
```

Observe que a leitura só acontece após o usuário teclar <kbd>Enter</kbd>. E isso supõe também que você não vá digitar mais de 50 caracteres por vez.

Comment: Melhor ainda é dizer `scanf(" %49s", vetor);`  que **garante** que o `scanf()` não vai ler mais que 49 caracterres de uma vez (deixando o 50º livre para ganhar o `'\0'` terminador).